# knockout.js.com Cart editor example - add total tax

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I found a cart editor example from [knockoutjs.com](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html) and was wondering how to add additional information such as "tax" and the corresponding values to external sampleproductcategories.js and calculate "total tax" on form?
Here is the jsfiddle for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/adNuR/

```
function formatCurrency(value) {
return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't see any reference to tax in the fiddle?

Comment: Hi Andrew no that's what I would like to add. The sampleproductcategories.js only has "name" and "price" but I would like to add "tax" as well and have the calculation total below the total value.

Comment: so what have you tried and not had success with?

Comment: Well I'm assuming its as simple as an additional data bind. Im quite new to this so thanks for sticking with me here!I first downloaded the external js file and added the class "tax":xx after the "price" to the model then uploaded the file to my own server. I tried to add an additional class to both the html and javascript calling functions directly to the tax class. However every time I change the code it wont even populate the drop down lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the html first add the tax for each row:

```
<td class='tax'>
    <span data-bind='visible: product, text: formatCurrency(tax())' > </span>
</td>
```

Then add the total tax:

```
<p class='totalTax'>
    Total value: <span data-bind='text: formatCurrency(totalTax())'> </span>
</p>
```

In CartLine add:

```
self.tax = ko.computed(function() {
    var taxRate = 0.1;
    return self.subtotal() * taxRate;
});
```

This will add tax for each line. It's currently set to 10%.

In Cart add:

```
self.totalTax = ko.computed(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $.each(self.lines(), function() { total += this.tax() })
    return total;
});
```

This just adds up the tax for all the rows.

If each product had it's own fixed tax amount such as:

```
{
    "name": "1948 Porsche 356-A Roadster",
    "price": 53.9,
    "tax": 5.39
}
```

self.tax in CartLine would be:

```
self.tax = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.product() ? self.product().tax * parseInt("0" + self.quantity(), 10) : 0;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to pick your brains a little further if you don't mind? would it be possible to add the tax as a fixed rate in the external file?

Comment: Would it work to call the tax from the UI itself with self.tax = ko.observable();

Comment: In my first snippet I'm getting the value of tax. Generally to get it in the uu you would do something like this: <span data-bind="text: tax"></span>

Comment: Do you mean have tax as a fixed amount set for each product?

Comment: yes! :) each product has a fixed amount set for each product

Comment: Hi Wayne Ive added the change however, the drop down lists deactivate for some reason? Ive added my new fiddle here for you to see http://jsfiddle.net/littledreamer/adNuR/3002/

Comment: The problem is with the data file. You are missing a comma after the price. If look at the console in chrome you can click on the syntax error.

Comment: Its working! Thank you so much Wayne! Really appreciate all your help :)